# EmberJS - Calling components methods from outside with a couple solutions (call for discussion)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

*The following is from an issue I posted on EmberJS GitHub, but Stack Overflow is better suited for a discussion than GitHub.*

I am building a few complex components at the moment including composite components and I hit a roadblock with the extreme isolation components live in.
There are several cases where I don't need the components to trigger an action on a controller, but where a controller needs to trigger a behaviour change on the component.
Problems is that the components don't know about the controller and the controller is not creating the components either: they are defined in a template.

I kind of solved the problem by subclassing the `Ember.Component` class to offer a way for messages to get through components.

The new component subclass breaks the on purpose isolation of components that shouldn't know about the outer controller.
The 2 less invasive options I found to make component methods calls from outside are:

- Cache component / name of instance pairs in a global array like
  `App.components`, then call a component method with
  `App.components['name'].method()`
- Trigger events from outside, register and handle them in the
  components. However in that case I am passing an *eventSource* object
  to the component, often a controller like so: `{{my-component
  eventSource=controller}}`

My question is about how could we solve this problem in the most elegant and less invasive way possible for components ?
For achieving composite components, using the components like lego pieces, it seems impossible to me at the moment to see how we can achieve that goal without breaking the components isolation.

Any input, ideas, solutions, discussion is very welcome.

**Note:** By the way, the first method that breaks the component isolation is inspired by the work done on the ember-bootstrap components: https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember
The author had to solve the same problem of being capable of triggering methods inside the components from outside.

**Another note:** Just for the record, another way to access a component is to use `Ember.View.views['name']` where name is a view name you gave to your component. However I feel dirty to make such calls, even more from a controller.

Comment: What kind of actions would your 'controllers' be sending to the component?

Comment: And is there any major reason you are using components, considering the fact that you want out of the isolation of components?  Might not views be an easier solution?

Comment: Both good questions: one simple example might be to show/hide/grey out a component in response of something happening elsewhere. The Ember components are a very nice construct similar to the new Web components to encapsulate a reusable piece of HTML alongside its Javascript behaviour. My problem is that by default, they go one way only. This is great since it guarantees they are not tightly coupled with other pieces of your code, but I am sure you can achieve both directions and still make them independent. At the moment, the event based solution I use achieves my goal but I am not happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I would try to solve this by binding properties to your component, which could then change according to computed properties or observers based on those properties.

For instance, instead of trying to call a method like `deactivate` on a component, bind a property such as `active` to a property in the template:

```
{{my-component active=formEnabled}}
```

I'm hesitant to recommend passing an `eventSource` to components as a general solution (like your `{{my-component eventSource=controller}}` example). I imagine this could work with a class or mixin that just emits specific events and is tightly coupled with your component, but I'm struggling to come up with a use case that justifies this approach.

Comment: I wonder if this could work with something like ember-bootsrap modal, ie imagine the modal as component, how would you tell the modal to hide or not weither an action on the controller has succeed or failed ?

Comment: I don't see modals as a very good fit for components. My approach is to create a base modal view class that is then extended for particular views. The base modal view handles all the modal-specific logic, and the individual modal view instances can interact with their controllers as needed.

Comment: Take a look at this project on Github which received some praise from Ember developers (and use method #1 I described): https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember - Look at the modal component which I think is easy to use as a component, more elegant than views, and the content can be changed easily. Another example is the notifications component, which can be triggered from anywhere in your code. My concern is that if you stick to the current components limitations, then they are limited to very simple constructs. Real apps requirements quickly outgrowth their capabilities.

Comment: Thanks @DanGebhardt for the answer. In fact, I do use property binding a lot to avoid as much as possible using events. At the end of the day, one of the reasons I ended using that eventSource solution is because it was not always practical and many components where ending up with too many parameters and it also meant polluting controllers with many properties. However this might still be the most "Emberish" way.